# What does the word 'vegetating' mean in this phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Phrase:

> Your enormous mind literally **vegetating** by your own hand

---

[Video](https://youtu.be/-oMtKsU7bSY?t=124) with the phrase

One more link to the same [video](https://kimcartoon.me/Cartoon/Rick-and-Morty-Season-3/Episode-3?id=76398) with phrase *(20:21)*

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vegetate) meanings

---

Guesses:

1) According to the Oxford Dictionary, the meaning **2.1** *(Cause plants to grow in)* the most appropriate

2) Nevertheless, I think she said about inserting his own consciousness into another entity (pickle)

---

Question:

> What does the word 'vegetating' mean in the phrase *'Your enormous mind literally **vegetating** by your own hand'*?

Comment: becoming vegetable-like, that is, lacking awareness/sentience/intelligent vitality. But "literally" is doubtful.

Comment: The construction *vegetating by your own hand* sounds clumsy and unnatural to me. It's only remotely credible because the surreal context (cartoon therapist talking to a pickle) plays heavily on the "vegetable/vegetate" pun. Note that ***to veg / vegetate*** is a common slang usage today meaning to pass one's time in a dull, inactive, unchallenging way (as a consequence of which it's implied the mind becomes weaker, through lack of "mental exercise").

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I know by their very nature cartoons are "fantastical" rather than "realistic", but in this exact context I'd say ***literally*** there is part of the wordplay/punning (given the addressee really ***is*** drawn as a pickled gherkin at the time! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Technically, cucumbers are fruits, not vegetables :)  What really happened is that I couldn't see the video for some reason and had no clue that it was a pickle being spoken to.

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo [one more link](https://kimcartoon.me/Cartoon/Rick-and-Morty-Season-3/Episode-3?id=76398)  time is 20:21

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: So even the cited context doesn't *quite* involve a "literal" usage! Curiously though, whereas the distinction would literally pass unnoticed by most people in literal contexts, we'd all understand a *huge* difference in metaphorical meaning with *Don't talk to him. He's a **fruit*** (as opposed to *...he's a **vegetable***).

Comment: The word "vegetating" refers to decaying or falling into a state of disability.

Comment: Look at definition 1  in the link that you quoted: that is exactly the intended sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the mind "vegetating" is referring to the act of putting itself into a vegetative (or vegetable-like) state. Such a state is defined as "A chronic state of brain dysfunction in which a person shows no signs of awareness."

Sourced definition from the Mayo Clinic